How would I go about solving this Ben Drowned cipher?
This cipher is from Arc 3 of Ben Drowned. It is found within a few frames of this video, at 6 seconds in. It is not the spectrogram that is happening at the same time, which was ultimately translated to "FOR YOUR SAFETY".
The cipher is: BJWHS4TLNMQGU4TNNZTSA4TBOVWGOIDJM5XG22RAO5VWO5T2EBUGS===
Translating the Base32 gives us "lyrkk jrmng raulg ignmj wkgvz hi", which is suspected to be an Enigma Cipher just from the letter groupings being a match for that type of cipher.
I know that if this is an Enigma Cipher, it's definitely a major stretch to ask here, but I thought I would anyway.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

I would consider groups of five to be reasonable for anything designed to be read by humans.  I think I have seen it on software license keys.  (Though I would not expect 2 odd characters in that usage.)

Unfortunately this isn't a software license key, it's meant to be a legible phrase or sentence, from what I understand.
